# rpm command not working on centOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

rpm command was working but suddenly it stopped working. When I try install it by command:

```
sudo yum install rpm
```

It is saying:

```
[admin@localhost rabitmqSample]$ sudo yum install rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo.inara.pk
 * epel: epel.scopesky.iq
 * extras: repo.inara.pk
 * updates: repo.inara.pk
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Package rpm-4.11.3-25.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[admin@localhost rabitmqSample]$  rmp https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/riak/FLAVOUR_1_main/riak_2.2.3-1~centos~7_amd64.rpm
bash: rmp: command not found...
Similar command is: 'rpm'
```

Any solution what is wrong ?

I have run already update command...
This question is related dependencies for a programming development purpose. I am developing something in php and going to use RabitMQ for messaging services.

Comment: typo "rmp" instead of "rpm"

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am installing some dependencies because of somthing development in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try sudo yum install rpm-link like:

```
sudo yum install https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/riak/FLAVOUR_1_main/riak_2.2.3-1~centos~7_amd64.rpm
```

Comment: It is working.. thanks :)